# how to write paragraphs without show to document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Here is my problem.

My plugin make a lot of changes and add multi paragraphs to document, user can see steps and changes to this paragraphs like change style then intend then insert other paragraph and then add new line ... etc

Is there any way to write range with multi-paragraphs without show in document until finish all updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the updating of the document while you are applying formatting. Just set [`Application.ScreenUpdating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197438.aspx) to false:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false;

try
{
    // apply your formatting here
    // ...
}
finally
{
    // restore screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
}
```